# Update ObservableCollection from another thread

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, .net-4.0

I have a problem. Look for a lot, but can not find the solution. I need, from another thread, update an ObservableCollection without the UI freeze. I'm using NET4.0. 
This code does not allow me to see the "ProgressRing" and "Searching" message. Thx!

```
private void Search()
    {

        ShowMessage = "Searching..."; // Message while the search is made.

        IsBusy = true; // Show WPF Toolkit BusyIndicator

        ShowProgressRing = true; // To show a ProgressRing in BusyIndicator

        Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {

            Articles = new ObservableCollection<Article>();

            /////////////////////////////
            //// Simulate SQL query ////
            ///////////////////////////

           for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
           {
               Articles.Add(new Article
               {
                   Code = i.ToString(),
                   Name = "PRODUCT NAME",
                   Price = 1m
               });
           }

        }).ContinueWith(x =>
        {

            IsBusy = false; // Hide

        }, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());

    }
```

**EDIT**

```
private bool _showProgressRing;

public bool ShowProgressRing
{
    get { return _showProgressRing; }
    set
    {
        _showProgressRing = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged("ShowProgressRing");
    }
}

private bool _isBusy;

public bool IsBusy
{
    get { return _isBusy; }
    set
    {
        _isBusy = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged("IsBusy");
    }
}

private string _showMessage;

public string ShowMessage
{
    get { return _showMessage; }
    set
    {
        _showMessage = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged("ShowMessage");
    }
}
```

My VM inherit from ViewModelBase (MVVM Light)

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that your ShowMessage is defined that way:

```
     private string _ShowMessage ;
    public string ShowMessage 
    {
        get
        {
            return _ShowMessage;
        }
        set
        {
            this.Set<string>("ShowMessage ", ref this._ShowMessage , value);
        }
    }
```

Same thing with your IsBusy property:

```
         private string _IsBusy ;
    public bool IsBusy
    {
        get
        {
            return _IsBusy ;
        }
        set
        {
            this.Set<bool>("IsBusy ", ref this._IsBusy , value);
        }
    }
```

and Same for

```
         private string _ShowProgressRing;
    public bool ShowProgressRing 
    {
        get
        {
            return _ShowProgressRing;
        }
        set
        {
            this.Set<bool>("ShowProgressRing", ref this._ShowProgressRing, value);
        }
    }
```

and the whole class is inheriting from `ObservableObject` , did you do that ?

Comment: what about the article class ?

Comment: Its a simple class, have only 5 parameters

Comment: and it is implementing the same Interface?